# Deletion of information stored in data.archive

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to coding in Swift, and I'm currently creating quite a simple app, where users can type information in textfields, which in the end is saved through dataArray, and later on sent to a server.

I currently have 2 problems, which I can't seem to find a proper solution to:

1. When I use dataArray, and connect text-fields to these Arrays, I need to do it for several ViewControllers. It works perfectly fine on the first Viewcontroller i did it, but on the second one, it says that there's some kind of "double-booking" on there Arrays. Is it possible to save 2 textfields to dataArray [0] and [1] and then later on, using the same dataArray for other textfields?
2. When I stored information from the first Viewcontroller (that worked), it, of course, keep showing the textfield information (like a specific type of material), whenever I run the simulation. But what I'd like to do is:

   - When text has been entered in a textfield on a viewcontroller, it has to save it to the data.archive if the app crashes or a call comes in (so the already entered data isn't deleted). (this works for the first viewcontroller)
   - When the data has been entered in the textfields, the general idea is, that the information is sent to a server, when a UIButton in the app is pressed. (this is where I'd like to remove the information from the data.archive, so the next time they open the app,the textfields are empty.

Sorry for the long explanation. Please feel free to ask question, if some of all this text isn't clear enough :)

Thank you
- Christian